# Tableau: How to display the maximum sales category name using a group function?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the data something like below:

Input

```
Year    Region  Sales   Team Name
2014    East    30  Team1
2014    East    26  Team2
2014    East    28  Team1
2014    West    40  Team1
2014    West    34  Team2
2014    North   56  Team1
2014    North   50  Team2
2014    South   24  Team1
2014    South   32  Team2
2014    South   19  Team3
2015    East    35  Team1
2015    East    42  Team2
2015    East    54  Team3
2015    West    41  Team1
2015    West    43  Team2
2015    West    40  Team3
2015    North   38  Team1
2015    North   32  Team2
2015    North   41  Team3
2015    South   28  Team1
2015    South   29  Team2
```

I am trying to achieve the output as below: 
Output

```
2014    East    Team1
2014    West    Team1
2014    North   Team1
2014    South   Team2
2015    East    Team3
2015    West    Team1
2015    North   Team3
2015    South   Team2
```

For each region category with-in the year, I have to display the name of the team that made maximum sales. I am able to display the maximum sales quantity on a tabular format by giving condition MAX(SALES) but I am not able to display the team name. When I am including the team name in the columns or in the TEXT field, I am getting all other rows for that year as well.

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the RANK formula and then filter on that for 1. Adjust the Compute Using as needed depending on your layout.

```
rank(sum([Sales]))
```

Take a look at the sample workbook here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/161116%20stack%20question.twbx

Comment: Probably good to note that there could be more than 1 team ranked as #1 per year and region.